# ASP.Net C#: submit image/documents to web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, linq-to-entities

I am developing RESTAURANT web site.  I have a form that allows restaurant owners to submit details about their restaurant.  I would like to allow them to submit an image and text document(e.g., menu) to the web site. I am planning on storing the images as a BLOB in the database and I am not sure how to store the large text documents in the database which I assume will either be a WORD document or a PDF.

Being a newbie to programming, I was wondering about the best strategy for capturing this information?  Should I store the submitted items first in a file in a directory and then pass them to the database or is there some sort of way that I can omit that step and hold them in some sort of control and pass them directly to the database when I add the restaurant record to the database?

Thanks in advance for any guidance on the best approach!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on SQL 2008 or greater, you can also look at using the new FileStream features:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd695918.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest saving the images / pdfs / etc. to the filesystem and simply storing the path to the files in the database.

Comment: I will have to do a synchronization process for images in case of change in server.

Comment: I would still try to find some way to use the file system. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/12/13/sql-server-do-not-store-images-in-database-store-location-of-images-url/ for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can create folders based on user name or id and store images/documents there and store the location of images/documents in database.